# Slim Braille watch,which does not look like a watch

Tags: wearable-technology

Asking for a  friend. There is not a huge selection of Braille watches, but there are a few.

Is there a Braille watch that does not look like a watch? Just a slim wrist-wrap, like a fitness tracker or something?

Small is good. Tactile is necessary. 12 hour markers around a circular face are not. Looking like a watch is not. Also, sound is is not; just some slim thing on the wrist to quickly run a finger over and know the time.

Alternative to a wristband are acceptable; maybe a ring, key-fob, etc. Just not looking like a traditional watch. Could even be carried in a pocket, as opposed to worn on the wrist.

Bonus if it is solar powered and/or can be auto-synched from an atomic clock or [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/), although that seems incredibly unlikely.

Something like [this 10 year old KickStart project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1294391907/haptica-braille-watch) would be ideal, although slimmer would be preferable.

[image]

Or ...

[image]

Even better ...

[image]

.. but - something that can actually be bought.

Comment: Someone edited this question, so at least one perosn finds ir worthwhile. No comments?

Comment: That I approved the edit does not mean I know how to find the answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you. I just meant in general. I have given up hope on this one :-(